# Select Query Issue in InfluxDB

Tags: influxdb

When i use `int` in where condition it gives me result but when i use `string` it gives me error.

Gives result: `select * from dbname where version = 4`

Gives Error: `select * from dbname where name = abc`

***or***

`select * from dbname where name = 'abc'`

Comment: Add your error log, it could help.

Comment: @Michaël its my issue. Now its resolve. thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about :

```
select * from dbname where name = 'abc'
```

[The documentation on InfluxDB query language](http://influxdb.com/docs/v0.7/api/query_language.html#the-where-clause)

Comment: In doc its written you can use like this but its not working.